# Python Selenium import error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to execute some python project and I am getting following error:-

```
File "feed.py", line 17, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I installed selenium package by using pip command for both python2 and python3. If I run python on terminal, I don't get this error if I try to import selenium.

But project I am executing using venv. I am unable to figure out from where it is trying to look for selenium package.

When I execute python2.7/python/python on terminal and run 
`from selenium import webdriver`, I don't see any import errors. But the project when I execute is giving me error. I am unable to locate the path which is being looked up for selenium. How can I find it?

Comment: Did you install it systemwide or did you install it in the venv?  You have to enter your `venv` and THEN install it with `pip` so it installs in the venv.  Unless configured right at the time of the creation, the `venv` won't inherit the system modules store.

Comment: Initially i installed system wide and not in venv.Now i am trying to install in venv but it says package is already there.Please see my comment below the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to create a virtual environment for Selenium, which is okay, so, do as mentioned earlier. But I think the following is needed to install Selenium with Python on Ubuntu.

Since you are on Python2, so install Selenium like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-selenium # for Python2
```

And, if you want to move to Python3, then replace *python-selenium* with *python3-selenium* in the above command. Also, do remember to download Geckodriver for Firefox to further work with Selenium.

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.20.1/geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64.tar.gz
```

You would then need to extract the Geckodriver to a folder such as *~/.local/bin* for setting it on your execution PATH.

Answer (score 0):

First activate the virtual environment:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

... tthen your terminal will look like this:

```
(venv)$
```

Then install selenium:

```
(venv) $ pip install selenium
```

Then you will have selenium installed inside the `venv`.

The next time when you open a new terminal, just activate the `venv` and run your code.

Comment: I start running a script which has a statement "source venv/bin/activate".Now as you have mentioned,I ran source venv/bin/activate in a new terminal and then i got message as follow.

Comment: Collecting selenium
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.2)
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0

Comment: @BATEESH is your `venv` Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: When i run pyhton-v in venv,it shows following.python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1

Answer (score -2):

Instead of importing `webdriver` you can import your preferred browser `from selenium.webdriver`; in my case `import Firefox`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
```

Comment: Why do you think importing from `selenium.webdriver` will work when `selenium` itself can't be found?

Comment: I did not understand your question. Have you tried using the example I showed you?

Comment: Did you read the OP's question? Their error was that selenium itself couldn't be found. Why do you think that your answer would work in that case?